# How do you put words into a 3x3 grid using python

Tags: python

I need help 
How do you put words into a 3x3 grid

this is the code i have got so far

```
random.shuffle(words)
print[0-3]
print (words)
```

Comment: What is words ? what is your input? How do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
words = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]

random.shuffle(words) 

grouped = [words[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3)]
for l in grouped:
    print "".join("{:<10}".format(x) for x in l)
```

Output:

```
e         h         b         
i         c         g         
a         d         f
```

Remove the `random.shuffle(words)` line if you need the original `a,b,c,d,etc` order.